# How do I turn off the mature language filter?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3, every time someone uses an inappropriate word I see a bunch of random characters instead of what they are actually saying. I'm a fan of angry, curse-filled rants. I enjoy seeing the interesting, colorful language of people who are having a hard time in-game. Is there a way to turn off the language filter?

Comment: I keep finding it hilarious that the Dutch version of the verb "can" ("kunt") gets filtered out, it seems a little strict to me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After you are logged into your account select Options -> Social Tab -> Uncheck the box that reads "Mature Language Filter" in the bottom right hand corner.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think its in Options->Social near the 'allow quick join' setting. Will update the answer once I can login & check.